# NgRx Angular App not working with Redux DevTools

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

So I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Wy1AqY5gqE&t=310s) to get familiar with ngRx Entity, and for some reason my redux dev tools isn't 'lighting up' to indicate that it's in an app that is using redux, and the data I want to show up in the dev tools isn't showing up. The data showing up on the log monitor is this:

[image]

If I had to guess I would say it's some default data maybe?? I've also made sure that it's connected to my local host at the right port so I don't think that's the problem either.

I've troubleshot in the following ways:

1. Moving the storeDevToolsModule before the storeModule for root in the root module like this:

```
StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25,
    }),
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
```

2. I've used different browsers, and have enabled access to local URLs. [My Default Browser is Brave, and I troubleshot with Chrome].
3. I also instantiated a new react app with redux baked in and that worked fine, and the extension lit up and it detected the local store, so I don't think it's the extension.

I've looked for the past few days for resources that go over troubleshooting redux dev tools with angular & ngRx and have no idea what to do anymore. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So make sure that ngrx is installed using the `ng add` syntax when you plan on using it in the project. using npm install @ngrx/store @ngrx/entity gave me problems. So it started working when I typed `ng add @ngrx/store @ngrx/store-devtools @ngrx/entity`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you import all modules from the store first before importing the `StoreDevtoolsModule` in the list of imports.